# Get Action parameters from mvc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to get the parameters of a request on exception and log them.  How can I get action parameters from a request if the parameter is an object in asp.net mvc?  I can only get the parameters if I send in the parameters like this:

```
public virtual ActionResult TestAction(string A,string B){
}
```

But not like this:

```
public virtual ActionResult TestAction(ObjectQuery query){
}
```

My code:

```
protected override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
{
    string action = filterContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString();
    string controller = filterContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString();
    string parameters = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.QueryString
}
```

**EDIT:**
QueryString returns empty: 
[image]

Comment: Try `filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Params`

Comment: @DavidTansey gets only some weired params there. "WT_FPC", "ALL_HTTP", "ALL_RAW" etc.

Comment: Are you against using the `Request.Form` object?  If you look through that you will get the name and value that was posted to the server.  Does this not fit all your needs?

Comment: @Justin the Request.Form returns {} empty data. But when having methods like method(string a, string b) then the Request form has the correct data.

Comment: Are you `Getting` or `Posting`?

Answer (score 0):

You should use reflection to achieve this:

```
var parameters = MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().GetParameters();
foreach (ParameterInfo param in parameters)
{
    //do your logging here
}
```

Comment: this wont work because the logging is in the method "OnException"

Comment: No problem - get the first of the stacktrace like this:

StackTrace stackTrace = new StackTrace();
var parameters  = stackTrace.GetFrame(1).GetMethod().GetParameters();

Comment: But if the request traverse through many methods is it still possible to do it like this? or do i have too loop through the frames?

Answer (score 0):

I maybe over simplifying it, but you can get the parameters passed to the action using the `Request.Form` or `Request.QueryString`.  The nice thing about them is they are of the type `NameValueCollection` which makes it easy to merge them together.

Then the exception is being thrown on the respective controller so you can get the method signature via reflection, albeit without the named parameter.

Using the simple code below properly gave the parameters passed to the action and doesn't care if it is a **POST** or **GET** operation.

```
protected override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
    {
        //Get all the info we need to define where the error occured and with what data
        var param = new NameValueCollection {Request.Form, Request.QueryString};
        var controller = filterContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString();
        var action = filterContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString();
        var signature = filterContext.Controller.GetType().GetMethod(action).ToString();

        //Let's write it to the stream in this case
        Response.Write(string.Format("<h3>Controller: {0}</h3>", controller));
        Response.Write(string.Format("<h3>Action: {0}</h3>", action));
        Response.Write(string.Format("<h4>Signature: {0}</h4>", signature));

        foreach (var key in param.AllKeys)
        {
            Response.Write(string.Format("<strong>Key:</strong> {0} = {1}<br />", key, param[key]));
        }

        Response.End();
    }
```

There are some downsides I would imagine though.  Collections will probably be represented in a very unfriendly way.  Data which wasn't supposed to bind with the specific model will be shown as well.

Comment: I dont get any parameters from the Request.QueryString. I will try to post a image when im at work.

Comment: The `QueryString` or `Form` objects should have something in them provided you are passing data to the server.  These are available all time time as model binding works off them, unless you have an issue with your server instead of your code...

Comment: I have edited my question with an image of the querystring. And it is empty. Maybe there is something wrong with my localhost.

Comment: Are you doing a `POST` or `GET`?  `Post` parameters only show up in the `Request.Form` property.  `GET` parameters only show up in the `Request.QueryString` property.

Comment: Im doing POST. I did find out why i didnt get the parameters. It is because im using Unity Interceptions. im losing the parameters on the way to the "OnException" method.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Unity enough to help with that.  But if the exception is still being raised on the controller, it should be there.  Unity would being doing a big no-no by removing needed information.